# Special arrow in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need to have a special arrow symbol:  `\rightsquigarrow` with two arrow heads such as:

`\rightsquigarrow ->`

and I cannot use `tikz` as I have a special class.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `trimclip` in order to clip the arrow head and join it to the main symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\twoheadrightsquigarrow}{%
  \rightsquigarrow\joinrel\mathrel{\mathpalette\rsahead\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\rsahead}[2]{%
  \clipbox{{.7\width} 0pt 0pt -1pt}{$#1\rightsquigarrow$}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\twoheadrightsquigarrow B_{\twoheadrightsquigarrow}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that the new symbol is as wide as the one with a single arrow head, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\twoheadrightsquigarrow}{%
  \rightsquigarrow
  \mathrel{\mspace{-6.5mu}}%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\rsahead\relax}%
  \mathrel{\mspace{6.5mu}}%
}

\newcommand{\rsahead}[2]{%
  \rlap{\clipbox{{.75\width} 0pt 0pt -1pt}{$#1\rightsquigarrow$}}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\twoheadrightsquigarrow B_{\twoheadrightsquigarrow}$

$A\rightsquigarrow B_{\rightsquigarrow}$

\end{document}
```

[image]